# SQL - Add constraint to entity using two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have this table called `pc_table`:

```
MODEL   SPEED   PRICE
1012    350     799
1001    700     799
1008    700     999
1013    733     1500
1010    750     699
1003    866     1500
1004    866     999
1005    1000    1499
1011    1100    1299
1009    1200    1699
1006    1300    2119
1007    1400    2299
1002    1500    2499
```

I have to add this constraint to my table:
`if speed < 1200: price must be less than 1500`

I wrote this line: `ALTER TABLE pc_table ADD CHECK (speed < 1200 AND price <= 1500);`

But It's incorrect, I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic that you want is:

```
ALTER TABLE pc_table ADD CHECK (speed >= 1200 OR price <= 1500)
```

You can also express this -- perhaps closer to your intent -- as:

```
ALTER TABLE pc_table ADD CHECK (NOT (speed < 1200 AND price > 1500) );
```

Note:  `NULL` values pass check constraints.  So if you want to disallow `NULL` values, then that would require an extra check.